# Parse, Set Data to User by ObjectID

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

I've been looking to try to set data to a User based on his ObjectID, so instead of doing:

```
var user = new Parse.User()
user.set('username','myUsername');
```

I want to be able to set data based on an existing ObjectID.

Say a user in my Data Browser has the ObjectID of `XX1`,

I want to be able to set a username based on that ObjectID.

Note that I have my objectID stored in a variable like so:

```
var uniqueID = XX1
```

so in other words, something like
`uniqueID.set('username','myUsername');`

I hope that someone can help me out here!

Comment: Is this inside of a function that the user calls?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by that. What I posted above was just an example to give you an idea of what I wanted to achieve.

Comment: But what kind of function are you calling this in? Does it have a request argument?

Comment: Just on document ready. Are you saying that I need to wrap the code in a specific sort of function to send data to the ObjectIDs

Comment: I already have the ObjectID I need stored in a var, I simply need to use .set to give it some info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
var query =  new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.equalTo("objectId", uniqueID);
query.first({
    success: function(result) {
        result.set('money', 20);
        result.save();
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log("None found.");
    }
});
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. However, wouldn't that be to create a new user (and assigning him my objectId)? I'm trying to set data to an existing user based on his objectId  (sorry if I wasn't clear or if I am mistaken).

Comment: Let's chat about this [here.](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60795/room-for-dehli-and-nottobrag)